# Getting fhat values of 0 in my bivariate kernel regression smoothing function

Tags: r

I have written a kernel regression smoothing function below.

```
#simulated data: b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + e
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y <- 5 + 7 * x1 + 5 * x2 + rnorm(100,0,.1)
sample <- cbind(x1, x2, y)
sample <- as.data.frame(sample)

Kregsmooth2 <- function(sample, h){
  output <- matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
  grid.x1 <- seq(min(sample$x1), max(sample$x1), length.out = 100)
  grid.x2 <- seq(min(sample$x2), max(sample$x2), length.out = 100)
  for (j in 1:length(grid.x2)){
    for (i in 1:length(grid.x1)){
      output[i,j] <- sum(sample$y * dnorm((grid.x1[i]-sample$x1)/h)) * sum(sample$y * dnorm((grid.x2[j]-sample$x2)/h)) / (sum(dnorm((grid.x1[i]-sample$x1)/h)) * sum(dnorm((grid.x2[j]-sample$x2)/h)))
    }
  return(list(x1 = grid.x1, x2 = grid.x2, output=output))
  }
}

fit <- Kregsmooth2(sample, 1)
fit
```

When I run this function, in my output column, only the [,1] column is filled out. [,2:100] are populated with 0s. I have a feeling it's the way I'm storing the output, but I can't seem to figure out why I have this issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You put `return` inside the `j`-loop. Move it down below one `}`.